# Слитное написание "неспеша"

Tags: частица-не

Почему слитное написание "неспеша" считается ошибкой? Ведь данное слово может употребляться в положительном смысле и заменяться синонимом (медленно, слабоподвижно).

Мы рубили избу не быстро, а неспеша.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что слово "спеша" по факту является **деепричастием** (от глагола "спешить"), которые с частицей "не" пишутся раздельно, как и глаголы.

Но чистое наречие пишется вместе: ***неспешно***.

Comment: Можем ли мы сделать обобщение, что во всех случаях перехода из деепричастия в наречие слово пишется с "не" раздельно?

Comment: Можем. Но это всё равно деепричастие, которое выступает обстоятельством образа действия и **лишь сближается по функции с наречием** (и поэтому не обособляется). Розенталь: Указывая на образ действия, одиночное деепричастие обычно **приближается по значению к наречию или к сочетанию существительного с предлогом**, употребленному в обстоятельственном значении, и не обособляется.